# HTTP request callback not executing - why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, callback

I'm attempting to submit an HTTP POST request to a 3rd-party API. It's currently wrapped in a promise method.

The callback function is never executed, however when I run the code below just by itself, the call to the API is successful.

I'm fairly new to Node.js and the idea of an event-loop. What exactly is happening behind the scenes and why does the callback function not execute?

**Code:**

```
// SQL Query successfully called and passed into done() function
.done(function(sqlResult) {

// contact already exists. resolve the issue
if(sqlResult[0]) {
    deferred.resolve("Contact already exists in database.");
}

// no contact found. create new HubSpot contact
else {
    console.log("No contact found. Creating HubSpot contact...");

    // create the POST data object
    var postData = querystring.stringify({
        'email': contact.email,
        'firstname': contact.first_name,
        'lastname': contact.last_name,
        'hs_context': JSON.stringify({
            'hutk': contact.cookie,
            'ipAddress': hs_context.ipAddress,
            'pageUrl': hs_context.pageUrl,
            'pageName': hs_context.pageName
        })
    }),

    // set POST options
    options = {
        hostname: 'forms.hubspot.com',
        path: '/uploads/form/v2/xxxxxx/' + formID,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': postData.length
        }
    };

    // set up request
    console.log("Setting up HubSpot API request.");
    var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
        // THIS CALLBACK DOES NOT EXECUTE
        console.log("TEST - INSIDE REQUEST CALLBACK.");
        console.log("Status: " + response.statusCode);
        console.log("Headers: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log("Body: " + chunk);
        });
    });

    // handle any errors
    request.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Problem with request - " + e);
    });

    // Post the data
    console.log("Posting data.");
    request.write(postData);
    request.end();
} // end of else 

...
```

**Output:**

```
No contact found. Creating HubSpot contact...
Setting up HubSpot API request.
Posting data.
```

Any suggestions? I received the code from Hubspot's API docs - http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form - and tweaked to fit my needs.

**Update:**

I've noticed several of my tests have succeeded in making the API call. None of the `console.log()` are displaying, but when I go to the 3rd-party website I see every now and then the API call is successfully made.

I've made a quick time stamp at when I ran my tests.

```
12:09:12 - Unsuccessful
12:10:45 - Unsuccessful
12:11:05 - Unsuccessful
12:11:14 - Unsuccessful
12:11:32 - Successful!
```

I'm still struggling to understand how this can happen ...

Comment: Since this callback will fire asynchronously, maybe `request.end()` being fired immediately after `request.write()` is messing up the request before it can properly fire and execute its callback?

Comment: @EnKrypt - Suppose this is the case. I don't have any other code to execute between `request.write()` and `request.end()`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with how you set up the request and send it. Are you sure that the API is responding to your request? Maybe something else is going wrong? Try listening to the `error` event with `req.on('error', function (e) {console.log(e)})`.

Comment: @CanIbanoglu - I am 100% sure. I'm looking at the 3rd-party website right now and I can see the data I submitted to it. I also added the `error` event but to no avail. Nothing new happens.

Comment: Taking a look at [the doc for `request.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback), they've passed the callback as a parameter. Maybe try that?

Comment: Do you have access to Wireshark or Fiddler (if you're on Windows)? I'm truly curious about this. I can't find anything wrong with the request, I just would like to know if you do receive a response from the API (an HTTP response). You could also listen to the `aborted` event to see if the server hangs up. But definitely try Wireshark.

Comment: @EnKrypt - I just looked at the documentation you linked and I've now tried three different ways:  `request.write(postData); request.end();`, `request.end(postData, 'utf8');`, and finally the callback `request.end(function() { request.write(postData); });`. These **all** work - meaning the 3rd-party website is displaying the information I submitted it, but **only** after attempting 3-4 times for each.

Comment: @CanIbanoglu - I'll take a look using Wireshark to see if I receive any responses. I will get back to you.

Comment: I'm an idiot! I'm testing with Mocha and I forgot to wrap my testing code in a `describe/it` format. My request was always being executed but the test program terminated before any response to could be received. Now my program waits until a `done()` function executes before the program finishes. The issue is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to mention I am using Mocha for testing. The testing code did not have `describe/it` wrapped around it, so the code would finish executing before any response is received. I changed my testing code to the following:

```
describe("Submitting form to HubSpot API", function() {
    it("should return 204 status code", function(done) {
        test.createContact(contact, context, formID)
        .done(function(response) {
            test.log("CreateContact resolved! SUCCESS: " + response);
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
            test.log("CreateContact rejected! ERROR: " + response);
        })
        .always(function() {
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

And I finally receive a response!